# Check whether a static library contains a main function in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, sqlite, program-entry-point

I'm writing a trivial windows console application that links to a bunch of static libraries via a

```
#pragma comment(lib, "SomeLibrary.lib");
```

(Amongst these libaries is SQLite3.lib)

When I start my program,  the code in my main function doesn't seem to be executed, but instead the command line propt of the sqlite console application appears. Strange, isn't it? The only thing I can imagine causing this is that somehow another main function is defined somewhere else (supposedly in the static sqlite library) and that one is exectuted.

Is that possible? Is there some way to find out if there's a main function defined in a static library? And is there some way to give my main function precedence over the other one?

Comment: Use MS `dumpbin` utility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sqlite3.lib` library has a `main` function because you compiled the source code of the SQLite command-line shell into it.

Compile that library without `shell.c`.
It should contain nothing but `sqlite3.c`.

Comment: Thats it. I just right now figured it out by myself. Thanks anyways. For everyone that encounters similar issues: In Visual Studio I just started the  debugger with F10 and it jumps right to the main function of SQLite.